# GA Tracking on Playing of Video in iFrame in Lightning Component

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, lightning-components

Google Tag Manager is not picking up that a video is clicked for playing in a Lightning component where the video is in an iFrame.  Thoughts?

```html
<iframe src="{!'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + v.VideoURL2 + '?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0'}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you done anything to inspect the traffic from the page? When clicked, is there any network information that comes up?

Comment: I am successfully using Tag Manager to track visits to the page & clicks on the page.  However, I cannot seem to capture anything related (clicks of any form) to the Youtube video when it is in an iframe in a component or embedded in a rich text field.  I have been trying to use the Video trigger of Tag Manager.